# Set a parameter through ROS services

Tags: ros, parameters, rosparam, rosservice, services

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi to everyone,

Yesterday I was going through the parameters of my work environment in ROS. One of my colleagues told me that if I need to change a parameter I should do it within rosservice and not by doing:

```
rosparam set /pathToTheParameter/parameterUniqueName
```

He was not able to explain me why but I would like to understand it.

Someone of you could please help me?

Thanks.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/199840/set-a-parameter-through-ros-services/) by [fabbro](https://answers.ros.org/users/20381/fabbro/) on ROS Answers with karma: 115 on 2014-12-19

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

He might be talking about the dynamic_reconfigure package.
http://wiki.ros.org/dynamic_reconfigure

---

Originally posted by [kmhallen](https://answers.ros.org/users/3102/kmhallen/) with karma: 1416 on 2014-12-19

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [fabbro](https://answers.ros.org/users/20381/fabbro/) on 2014-12-27**:
Thanks for the reply. I will give a look to it as soon as possible.